# UIImageView in UITableViewCell doesn't display for a condition

Tags: swift2, ios9.3

I am displaying an UIImageView inside a custom UITableViewCell for only those cells that have image URL set in Firebase response. Code as below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  let cellIdentfier = "ArticleTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentfier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!ArticleTableViewCell

    //Configure the cell
    // Added by ankit khanna for UIImageView change

    let imageURL = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    print ("Final Image URL: [\(imageURL)]")

    if (imageURL == "NIL") {
        cell.articalImageView.hidden = true
    }

         let fileUrl = NSURL(string: imageURL as String)
        print ("File URL : [\(fileUrl!)]")
         cell.articalImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(fileUrl!)


    // End
}
```

Issue is if i remove the if condition `if (imageURL == "NIL")` image displays correctly but then when i scroll back up image starts to show up where it shouldn't show up.

Image Array : `var imageArray = [String]()`

Below is the code where I am appending the array

```
            if (snapshot.value.objectForKey("image") != nil)
        {
            let url = snapshot.value.objectForKey("image")!
            let f_url = String(url)
        //    print ("image1 URL : \(f_url)")
            self.imageArray.append(f_url)
        }
        else if (snapshot.value.objectForKey("image") == nil)
        {
            self.imageArray.append("NIL")
        }
```

How am I suppose to disable the UIImageView for the response where it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding

`cell.articalImageView.hidden = false` in the else statement.

Corrected code:

```
        if (imageURL == "NIL") {
        cell.articalImageView.hidden = true
    }
    else {
        cell.articalImageView.hidden = false
         let fileUrl = NSURL(string: imageURL as String)
        print ("File URL : [\(fileUrl!)]")
         cell.articalImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(fileUrl!)
    }
```